# Take first edge or level of the wave and ignore rest until reset

Tags: digital-logic

I have a pulse train of fixed frequency of 30kHz. when I connect it to the LED I get LED blink at 30kHz. What would be the way to detect the first edge/ level of the pulse train and ignore the rest, so i get the led to be lit without blinking. LED should turned off when a reset pin is activates.  A parallel capacitor will just smoother the oscillation, but a very large value will case delayed switch off which is undesirable. <strike>A digital circuit is expected.</strike>

Actually the TSOP receiver gets an modulated waveform to reject ambiance IR. So I want a way to connect the TSOP as a binary switch., with minimum possible components. No Micro-controller (as the person i am suggesting solution don't have experience)

i tried with `RS flip flop` but it is not working. 
[Schematic](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+285.9303473255704+50+5+50%0A151+256+160+368+160+0+2+0+5%0A151+256+288+368+288+0+2+5+5%0Aw+368+160+368+192+0%0Aw+368+192+256+256+0%0Aw+368+288+368+256+0%0Aw+368+256+256+192+0%0Aw+256+192+256+176+0%0Aw+256+256+256+272+0%0AM+368+288+448+288+0+2.5%0Ax+159+120+191+123+4+24+set%0Ax+438+138+456+141+4+24+Q%0Ax+147+281+200+284+4+24+reset%0Ax+438+266+456+269+6+24+Q%0AR+256+144+256+96+0+2+2+5+0+0+0.5%0A162+368+160+368+128+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+368+128+368+96+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ag+368+96+416+96+0%0A)

Comment: How would you know the pulse has gone away without using an RC time circuit? How would a digital circuit know that the pulse has gone away?

Comment: Yes valid point, I too thought after position.  there should be a separate reset pin. It shout be in ON state even if the input has gone. just editing the question.

Comment: Why is a digital circuit "expected"? Why not a microcontroller?

Comment: the person i am suggesting the solution does not have any experience with microcontroller. so was thinking if there is a wayout.

Answer (score 0):

you want a pulse stretcher eg 74123, a capacior is required for the 74123 to function, there's not really any way around that.

http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74123

[image: FIGURE 1 FROM DATASHEET[1]]

Comment: looks promising, will check it out